# How to parse FieldDecl with libclang?

Tags: c++, parsing, clang, libclang

Using the example Clang lambda, I'm trying to parse a c++ header file. The problem is, I'm unsure how to parse a `CXCursor_FieldDecl` for the type and name of a member field of a class.

```
clang_visitChildren(cursor,                                                 
    [](CXCursor c, CXCursor parent, CXClientData client_data) {             
                                                                            
        if (clang_getCursorKind(c) == CXCursor_FieldDecl) {            
            std::cout << clang_getCursorKindSpelling(clang_getCursorKind(c))
                << " " << clang_getCursorSpelling(c) << ";\n";
        }                                                                   
                                                                            
        return CXChildVisit_Recurse;                                        
    }, nullptr);
```

The above will print out:

```
FieldDecl varA;
FieldDecl varB;
FieldDecl varC;
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
int    varA;
double varB;
string varC;
```

Any thoughts on how to parse a FieldDecl for type and name of member field?

Comment: I'd look for a way to transform `CXCursor` into `clang::FieldDecl` class and call some of its methods to retrieve the type and the name instead of methods converting cursors to strings. Also, depending on how robust you want your parsing to be, handling strings at all may be a really bad solution, maybe look for "type resolution" API or something similar.

Comment: That actually makes sense, so if you want to make it an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: Also, if you know of any functions to help transform, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the variable is the spelling of the cursor.  The type of the variable is the spelling of the cursor type.  You may want to look at the documentation for `clang_getCanonicalType` as well.

```
std::string name = spelling(c);
std::string type = spelling(clang_getCursorType(c));
```